# Can you switch between windows within an application in Openbox?

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

Is it possible to set up a keybinding in Openbox for switching between open windows within an application? Just like you can in gnome 3 with alt + [key above Tab] .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have implemented this function by using wmctrl.

The relevant part in rc.xml of openbox:

```xml
<keybind key="A-space">
  <action name="execute">
    <execute>wmctrl-switch-by-application</execute>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

below is the code in wmctrl-switch-by-application:

```shell
# taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26546/can-you-switch-between-windows-within-an-application-in-openbox
# taken from: http://www.st0ne.at/?q=node/58

# get id of the focused window
active_win_id=$(xprop -root | grep '^_NET_ACTIVE_W' | awk -F'# 0x' '{print $2}')

# get window manager class of current window
win_class=$(wmctrl -x -l | grep $active_win_id | awk '{print $2 " " $3}' )

# get list of all windows matching with the class above
win_list=$(wmctrl -x -l | grep -- "$win_class" | awk '{print $1}' )

# get next window to focus on
switch_to=$(echo $win_list | sed s/.*$active_win_id// | awk '{print $1}')

# if the current window is the last in the list ... take the first one
if [ -z "$switch_to" ];then
   switch_to=$(echo $win_list | awk '{print $1}')
fi

# switch to window
wmctrl -i -a $switch_to
```

Comment: Thank you! If you want to use Alt-backspace as the toggle key, use `    <keybind key="A-grave">`

Comment: FYI: Anyone running a minimal ArchLinux installation will probably need to install `wmctrl` and `xorg-xprop`.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch among windows of all desktops, or even include the desktop itself and panels, as described in the [Openbox Actions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions#NextWindow) page, but there seem to be no way to switch among windows of the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between any open window or application by pressing alt and tab. Even if there are two open windows of the same program.